# DependencyProperty data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I try to bind my UI to custom DependencyProperty:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Localization x:Key="Localization" xmlns:x="#unknown" xmlns:local="#unknown"/>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid Name="mainStack" DataContext="{StaticResource Localization}">
         <Button Padding="10,3" Margin="5" Content="{Binding BtnAdd}" Command="New"/>
    </Grid>
```

Also I have class "Localization":

```
class Localization : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static DependencyProperty BtnAddProperty;

        static Localization()
        {
            BtnAddProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BtnAdd", typeof(string), typeof(Localization));

        }

        public string BtnAdd
        {
            set
            {
                SetValue(BtnAddProperty, value);
            }
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(BtnAddProperty);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventArgs e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
                handler.Invoke(this, e);
            }
        }

        public Localization()
        {
            BtnAdd = MainWindowRes.BtnAdd;
        }

        public void SwitchLanguage()
        {
            BtnAdd = MainWindowRes.BtnAdd;
            OnPropertyChanged("BtnAdd");
        }

    }
```

First time my UI element gets my property value. But when I use my method SwitchLanguage(), property gets new data, and UI still have first value.

Can someone help me please?

P.S.
Sorry, for my English.

Eugene

Comment: try explicitly setting Content binding to TwoWay

Comment: Thanks! But didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your example, everything seems to work.
But there are some pitfalls:

- There's a framework class called Localization, so make sure you don't mix up!
- How do you call `SwitchLanguage()`? You have to call this on the right instance! (For example in the Code Behind:

  var res = (Localization)Resources["Localization"];
  res.SwitchLanguage();

Comment: Thank you! 1. I renamed my class to avoid mixing. It did not help. 2. I call this method just from button click handler, in MainWindow.xaml.cs, on created instance of my class Localization.

Comment: I tried to call it like you said. And its working! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Can't really spot any mistake which would make the binding not update, but there are some other things that need to be fixed, the DP field should be readonly and you should not call any property change notifications for DPs as they have an internal mechanism for notifications (inside `SetValue`).

Are you sure the value of `MainWindowRes.BtnAdd` is actually different in `SwitchLanguage` from the value it has in the constructor?

Comment: Thank you, H.B.! I removed any notifications and set my DP as readonly. And, yes, that values are different. And it is still not working.

Comment: @Eugene: Try to address WaltiD's points then as i cannot think of anything else right now...